# Express $ G_y$ in terms of $G_x$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

A ﬁnite group $G$ acts on a ﬁnite set $X$, the action of $g \in G$ on $x \in X$ being denoted by $gx$. For each $x \in X$ the stabilizer of $x$ is the subgroup $G_x = \{g \in G : gx = x\}$. If $x, y ∈ G$ and if $y = gx$, then express $G_y$ in terms of $G_x$.

---

How can I able to solve this problem? I am totally stuck on it.

Comment: Actually, $G_x=G_y$

Comment: the given answer is $G_y = gG_xg{−1}$

Comment: What is action of G on X? Conjugation?

Comment: This is the complete question and nothing else is mentioned here.

Comment: Sorry, my answer is wrong. Look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88285/are-orbits-equal-if-and-only-if-stabilizers-are-conjugate

Comment: The assumptions that $X$ and $G$ are finite are not necessary and are not used in the proof, so I have no idea why they have been made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y = gx$ then $G_{y} = gG_{x}g^{-1}$ as we can easily verify.

Infact if $h\cdot y = y \Rightarrow h\cdot g\cdot x = g\cdot x \Rightarrow (g^{-1}hg)\cdot x = x \Rightarrow h\in gG_{x}g^{-1} $.

Viceversa if $k \in G_{x}$ then $(gkg^{-1})\cdot y = (gkg^{-1})\cdot (g\cdot x) = g\cdot x = y \Rightarrow gkg^{-1} \in G_{y}$.

Comment: Thank you for answer but I have the answer already but I could not solve it.Can you explain please.

Comment: @ghugni: I have edited

Comment: :thanks a lot and happy new year

Comment: In your first implication, $(g^{-1}hg)x = x$ implies $g^{-1}hg \in G_x$. How does it imply that $h \in gG_xg^{-1}$ ?