# Necessary and sufficient for $\operatorname{orb}(x)=\operatorname{orb}(y) \iff \operatorname{Stab}(x)=g\operatorname{Stab}(y)g^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[Are orbits equal if and only if stabilizers are conjugate?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88285/are-orbits-equal-if-and-only-if-stabilizers-are-conjugate#comment207914_88285)

You may get some insights from the link above.

My Question: What is the necessary and sufficient condition for the above statement to be true?

I can prove with no difficulty that same orbits implies conjugate stabilizer .For the converse, if $G$ is non trivial groups, is it strong enough to show the converse is true?
I guess it probably not working with only the condition but i couldn't get a **counter example.**

Any hints, counter example, ideas or related information would be appreciated.

Comment: Iguess ,Your title should be $Orb(x)= Orb(y) \iff Stab(x)=gStab(y)g^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

If $O(x)=O(y)$ then $Stab(x)$ and $Stab(y)$ are conjugate.

Since they are in same orbit, there exist a $g\in G$ such that $g*x=y$.

Now, let $r\in Stab(y)$ then 
$$r*y=y$$
$$r*(gx)=gx$$
$$(g^{-1}rg)*x=x$$ so $(g^{-1}rg)\in Stab(x)\implies g^{-1}Stab(y)g \leq Stab(x)$ to show other inclusion you can fallow similiar way then you are done.

Converse is not true. If $Stab(x)$ ans $Stab(y)$ are conjugate, you can not conclude that $O(x)=O(y)$. But you can say that $|O(x)|=|O(y)|$ by ortbir-stabilizer theorem.

Let $G=Z_2=\{0,1\}$ and $\omega=\{1,2,a_1,a_2 \}$ and the zero of $G$ fixes every element and $1_G$

$$1_G:1\to 2$$
$$1_G:2\to 1$$
$$1_G:a_1\to a_2$$
$$1_G:a_2\to a_1$$

You can check that $Stab(1)=Stab(a_1)$ so they are also conjugate to each other but $O(1)=\{1,2\}$ and $O(a_1)=\{a_1,a_2\}$.

Comment: do you know what is the sufficient condition for the converse to be right? Like if the stabilizer are normal? or if $X$ is a group or if x conjugate to y?

Comment: @Jorden I don't think a group theoretic property is enough to determine when elements are in the same orbit. However if $X=G$ and $x\sim y$ are conjugate then of course they have the same orbit (under the conjugation action).

Comment: @Jorden: Action of $G$ on different orbits are independent of each other Unless you put strong connection but when you put strong connection it becomes so obvious that it lost its meaning.